# check box checked by default in yii2 ActiveForm

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

I have `ActiveForm` checkbox:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'is_necessary')->checkbox(['uncheck'=> 0]) ?>;
```

I want to make it checked by default and when I check, it's value become 1 and when uncheck - 0. Can I achieve this without any `javascript`?

I tried :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'is_necessary')->checkbox(['uncheck'=> 0, 'value'=>false]) ?>;
```

option `'value'=>false` made my checkbox checked by default but then in controller I receive `NULL` nor either `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add in your controller or view (which is not recommended) below code

```
$model->is_necessary = true;
```

above code works fine. but you should add this code before your

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post)
```

method or assigining post data to your model. Otherwise your checkbox will be checked any time;

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to override `init()` inside your model

```
public function init() {
    parent::init ();
    $this->is_necessary  = 1;
}
```

and you don't need to pass the `'uncheck'=> 0,` as per the [**`DOCS`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#checkbox()-detail)

> `uncheck` : `string`, the value associated with the unchecked state of the
>   radio button. If not set, it will take the default value `0`. This
>   method will render a hidden input so that if the radio button is not
>   checked and is submitted, the value of this attribute will still be
>   submitted to the server via the hidden input. If you do not want any
>   hidden input, you should explicitly set this option as null.

Comment: thank you man! I already have your hope in learning yii, when I ask question about yii I know that you will answer :))

Comment: haha `:D` i appreciate that, I just love Yii and stackoverflow. @godot